# Laravel/Lumen include a column from pivot table into results of relationship eager loading

Tags: laravel, many-to-many, pivot-table, lumen

In my application a user can add other users to the "favorites" list. All information about favorite users is stored in a table with the following structure:

```
user_id
favorite_id
```

In addition, each user has its services with prices. There are `users` and `services` tables in my application that are related to each other with `service_user` table which has the following structure:

```
user_id
service_id
price
```

In order to get all favorite users of a particular user with their services and prices I do the following:

```
$user->favorites()->with('services')->get();
```

However, there's no `price` column in each service object of the resulting list of services (this column is located in `pivot`).

Therefore, I want to know if there's a way to get the `price` column as part of each service object, instead of being in pivot table. [The following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48276025/include-a-column-of-pivot-table-on-call-relationships) already solves my problem, but I want to know if there is way to do this without `map()` and/or `foreach()` to make performance better?

Currently, I have the following solution:

```
$user->favorites()->with('services')->get()
    ->map(function ($favorite) {
        foreach ($favorite['services'] as &$item) {
            $item['price'] = $item->pivot->price;
        }
        return $favorite;
    });
```

Comment: It would be better if you could explain your problem instead of providing a link to other question. Also, please tell us why don't you want the `map()` solution.

Comment: @linuxartisan I updated the question to explain my problem and unwillingness to use `map()` and/or `foreach()`